# Why does a temporary variable in Python change how this Pass-By-Sharing variable behaves?

Tags: python, recursion, pass-by-reference

first-time questioner here so do highlight my mistakes.

I was grinding some Leetcode and came across a behavior (not related to the problem) in Python I couldn't quite figure out nor google-out. It's especially difficult because I'm not sure if my lack of understanding is in:

1. recursion
2. the `+=` operator in Python or variable assignment in general
3. or Python's pass-by-sharing behavior
4. or just something else entirely

Here's the simplified code:

```
class Holder:
    def __init__(self, val=0):
         self.val = val

class Solution:
    def runThis(self):
        holder = Holder()
        self.diveDeeper(holder, 5)
        return 
        
    def diveDeeper(self, holder, n):
        if n==0:
            return 1

        # 1) Doesn't result in mutation
        holder.val += self.diveDeeper(holder, n-1)

        # 2) Also doesn't result in mutation
        # holder.val = holder.val + self.diveDeeper(holder, n-1)

        # 3) !! Results in mutations
        # returnVal = self.diveDeeper(holder, n-1)
        # holder.val += returnVal

        print(holder.val)
        return 1

a = Solution()
a.runThis()
```

So yeah my main source of confusion is how (1) and (3) look semantically identical to me but results in two completely different outcomes:

```
================ RESTART: Case 1 ===============
1
1
1
1
1
>>> 
================ RESTART: Case 3 ===============

1
2
3
4
5
>>>
```

From (2), it doesn't seem related to the `+=` operator and for brevity, I haven't included the tens of variations I've tried but none of them have given me any leads so far. Would really appreciate any pointers in the right direction (especially in case I get blindsided in job interviews lmao)

PS: In case this is relevant, I'm using Python 3.8.2

Comment: For people which gave negative vote on that, could you elaborate? For me the problem is totally clear, interesting and shows effort of someone who is completely new in the stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, if you have `expression1() + expression2()`, `expression1()` is evaluated first.

So 1 and 2 are really equivalent to:

```
left = holder.val
right = self.diveDeeper(holder, n - 1)
holder.val = left + right
```

Now, `holder.val` is only ever modified after the recursive call, but you use the value from before the recursive call, which means that no matter the iteration, `left == 0`.

Your solution 3 is equivalent to:

```
right = self.diveDeeper(holder, n - 1)
left = holder.val
holder.val = left + right
```

So the recursive call is made before `left = holder.val` is evaluated, which means `left` is now the result of the sum of the previous iteration.

This is why you have to be careful with mutable state, you got to understand the order of operations perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

You struggled me a bit but the answer is really simple. Let me rephrase why that happened.

```
holder.val = holder.val + self.diveDeeper(holder, n - 1) # prints 1 1 1 1 1
holder.val = self.diveDeeper(holder, n - 1) + holder.val # prints 1 2 3 4 5
```

I hope you see now what is going on - in case of `+=` it evaluates to first variant. In every recursion step, `holder.val` will be 0 when executing that line. That's why we will assign 5 times `holder.val = 0 + 1`.

With changed order, we first mutate `holder.val` and then use it to calculate new one. The passing by reference works as expected.

Comment: Aah I see it now. `holder.val` is read before the mutation due to the order of evaluation. I loved the brevity of your answer but it took me a while to process that when `holder.val` is read/evaluated, the expression becomes a static value. I hope you don't mind but I marked @Jasmijn's answer as the accepted one because of the added clarity they provided. Really appreciate the answer though.

Answer (score 2):

View bytecode with `dis`:

```
>>> from dis import dis
>>> dis('a.b += c()')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              2 DUP_TOP
              4 LOAD_ATTR                1 (b)
              6 LOAD_NAME                2 (c)
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             10 INPLACE_ADD
             12 ROT_TWO
             14 STORE_ATTR               1 (b)
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE

>>> dis('''r = c()
... a.b += r''')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (c)
              2 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              4 STORE_NAME               1 (r)

  2           6 LOAD_NAME                2 (a)
              8 DUP_TOP
             10 LOAD_ATTR                3 (b)
             12 LOAD_NAME                1 (r)
             14 INPLACE_ADD
             16 ROT_TWO
             18 STORE_ATTR               3 (b)
             20 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             22 RETURN_VALUE
```

An obvious difference is that the former has already loaded the value of `a.b` before calling the function, which will be 0 in each recursion. Because the number is an immutable object, the number loaded in advance will not be changed after each addition and storage. The latter is the value of `a.b` loaded after calling the function, which causes the value of `a.b` to be updated after each recursion.

Comment: I love assembly as much as the next guy but it would've been easier to follow if the explanation linked back to the python code :') A brilliant answer though, my brain's just not that brilliant. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

for case 1.

```
        holder.val += self.diveDeeper(holder, n-1)
```

here intial value of `holder.val` is 0. so effectivly `holder.val` should be equal to the value  of `self.diveDeeper(holder, n-1)`

since this function only return 1 and `holder.val` remain local variable it will remain 0 (initally) in all funciton call ie

WHEN N=5

```
holder.vaL = 0 + self.diveDeeper(holder, 5)
           = 0 + (0 + self.diveDeeper(holder, 4))
           = 0 + (0 + (0 + self.diveDeeper(holder, 3)))
           = 0 + (0 + (0 + (0 + self.diveDeeper(holder, 2))))
           = 0 + (0 + (0 + (0 + (0 +self.diveDeeper(holder, 1)))))
           = 0 + (0 + (0 + (0 + (0 +1))))
           = 1
```

note in each function call value is not stored anywhere

whereas in case 3

```
returnVal = self.diveDeeper(holder, n-1)
holder.val += returnVal
```

here, for each call `returnVal`  will have value of 1.
ie

```
n = 5, returnVal = self.diveDeeper(holder, 4) 
                 = self.diveDeeper(holder, 3) 
                 = self.diveDeeper(holder, 2)
                 = self.diveDeeper(holder, 1)
                 = self.diveDeeper(holder, 0)
                 = 1
```

so we got `returnVal = 1`. not comes the `holder.val part

since `holder` is an object and during function call this is keep passing in the functional calls, it will remain intact throughout

so for last call when n=0, `holder.val += returnVal` make `holder.val` = 1.
now when it return 1 , and goes to recursive chain when n=1, `holder.val` is updated to 1 and is not 0 anymore so

```
holder.val = 1 + self.diveDeeper(holder, 1)
```

ie all the reference to `holder.val` got update to latest call and is no more 0

```
ie when n = 0, holder.val = 0
        n =1, holder.val = holder.val ( value of holder.val when n= 0, ie 0) + 1 (1 is value of self.diveDeeper(holder, 0)
        n= 2 holder.val = holder.val ( value of holder.val when n= 1, ie 1) + 1 (1 is value of self.diveDeeper(holder, 1)
        n= 3 holder.val = holder.val ( value of holder.val when n= 2, ie 2) + 1 (1 is value of self.diveDeeper(holder, 2)
         n= 4 holder.val = holder.val ( value of holder.val when n= 3, ie 3) + 1 (1 is value of self.diveDeeper(holder, 3)
         n= 5 holder.val = holder.val ( value of holder.val when n= 4, ie 4) + 1 (1 is value of self.diveDeeper(holder, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

I thinks it comes from the way you're using recursion.

When you call `holder.val += self.diveDeeper(holder, n-1)` the holder you pass to the dive deeper method is the one without updated val.
So you will call n times the diveDeeper function without modifying the holder val, and you will return 1 in the end.

Your example will execute as follow:

1. call self.diveDeeper with holder unmodified, n = 5;
2. call self.diveDeeper with holder unmodified, n = 4;
3. call self.diveDeeper with holder unmodified, n = 3;
4. call self.diveDeeper with holder unmodified, n = 2;
5. call self.diveDeeper with holder unmodified, n = 1;
6. call self.diveDeeper with holder unmodified, n = 0;
7. return 1
8. print holder.val 5 times which as not been modified, since your last recursion return 1

In (3), after the recursion is done, when you unwrap your call, you will get 1 from the last diveDeeper call, then add it to holder. In the next unwrapping you'll do the same, resulting in incrementing your val from 1, on each recursion.